# How to fix "Multiple Marker" issue with the line <script type="text/javascript">?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I wanted to create a Spring MVC maven project. I created a `js` file that contained some `javascript` methods. So, the file looks like as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// some javascript methods

</script>
```

I'm getting the following errors in the first line.

```
 Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ">", ; 
     expected
    - Syntax error on tokens, delete 
     these tokens
```

How do I resolve the issue? What am I possibly missing in the project?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: theres an unexpected token ">", show code

Comment: No, there is not. Even If I comment out all the methods, I still get the 'Multiple markers' error.

Comment: IMSoP answer is it, if its an .js file you dont need the <script> tags, so the unexpected token is the script tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've shown there is the syntax for embedding JS into HTML, but you say this is a JS file, not an HTML one.

So just remove the `<script>` and `</script>` lines, and leave just the actual JS.